# Problema con el menu responsive

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tengo un menú responsive con una función de javascript para mostrar o ocultar el menú al hacer click en el botón sin embargo esta función no funciona.
Código javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const botonMenu = document.querySelector('btn-collapse');

    if (botonMenu) {
        
        botonMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const menu = document.querySelector('menu-contenedor');
            menu.classList.toggle('show');
        })
    }
})
```

El menu esta formado por dos ul, uno para el menu principal y el otro para el de inici/registro.
Código html

```html
<header>
    <span class="logo"><a href="#">LOG</a></span>
    <ul class="menu-contenedor">
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="login-contenedor login">
        <li><a href="">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Registrarse</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn-collapse">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
</header>
```

En cuanto a los estilos, en el primer breakpoint oculto el menú principal y debería mostrarse al pulsar el botón, en el siguiente breakpoint oculto ambos menús para luego mostrarlo al pulsar el botón, esta ultima parte aun no la implemente.
Código css

```css
@import "./nord-theme.css";

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--nord0);
}

.logo a {
    font-size: 35px !important;
}

.menu-contenedor,
.login-contenedor {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-contenedor li,
.login-contenedor li {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.menu-contenedor li a,
.login-contenedor li a,
.logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--nord4);
}

.btn-collapse {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--nord0);
    color: var(--nord4);
    font-size: 35px;
}

.show {
    top: 55px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

    header,
    .logo,
    .login-contenedor,
    .btn-collapse {
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .menu-contenedor {
        position: fixed;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: -105vh;
        background-color: var(--nord1);
        z-index: 10;
        transition: all .4s;
    }

    .menu-contenedor li {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    .btn-collapse {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    header {
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .login-contenedor {
        position: fixed;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: -100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

**--- MODIFICACION ---**
Hice la siguiente modificación en el codigo javascript para comprobar si funcionaba el evento

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const botonMenu = document.querySelector('.btn-collapse');
    console.log('DOM Cargado');

    if (botonMenu) {
        console.log('Comprobando el boton');

        botonMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const menu = document.querySelector('menu-contenedor');
            menu.classList.toggle('show');
            console.log('Estoy haciendo click');
        })
    }
})
```

Al poner los `console.log('mensaje');` me di cuenta que no entraba en el if por que faltaba un . para indicar la clase en la variable botonMenu.
Ahora hace click pero suelta el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado a que el JS meta directamente el estilo? Algo como `menu.style.top = '55px';`. Si esto funciona, creo que el problema es la prioridad de las clases

Comment: @Pablo Lozano probé a poner ```menu.style.top = '55px'``` pero no hace nada, incluso acabo de probar a poner ```console.log('Estoy haciendo click');``` para ver si salía el mensaje por consola cuando hago click y no aparece

Comment: Es una errata: `const botonMenu = document.querySelector('btn-collapse');` debería ser `const botonMenu = document.querySelector('.btn-collapse');` Lo mismo con `menu-contenedor`, debajo

Comment: @Pablo Lozano ya me di cuenta, deje una modificaron en la pregunta por que ahora da un error

Comment: Arreglado todo, el error era que falta poner el . para referenciar las clases en las variables y luego poner en el css ```top: 55px !important;```

Comment: @JPillado, el uso de `!important` es considerado una [mala práctica](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/html/cuales-son-las-implicaciones-de-usar-important-en-css/970982763/) porque anula la [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) y puede llegar a complicar el mantenimiento de tus estilos.

Comment: Dices que dejaste una modificación de lo que @PabloLozano observo, pero la misma modificación hace referencia a ese error que te esta resaltando

Comment: @Víctor Hugo Tirado cuando leí el comentario de Pablo Lozano me di cuanta y corregí el error y volví a probar para probar si funciona, en esta prueba me fije que se activaba el evento click del botón pero daba el error que aparece en la modificación y en ese momento decidí modificar la pregunta para agregar lo del error y después me dispuse a ver si daba con la solución. Cuando la encontró me di cuenta de que se trataba del mismo error pero en otra variable, lo corregí y funciono bien y acto seguido deje un comentario avisando que ya lo había solucionado y ese es el 5º comentario de la lista

Comment: En cuanto al ```!important``` ya me di cuenta de la especificidad, sin embargo como es algo que por el momento no afecta en nada a lo demás lo deje quedar